# Communication between android tablet and iphone

Tags: iphone, android, communication

hii,

I want to communicate between an iphone and an android tablet. The tablet as well as the iphone work on different 3g data services. Can any body give me an idea how to communicate and send messages between the devices...

Comment: I suspect it would be considerably easier to communicate via a 3rd party (i.e.: a web server), but perhaps I'll be proven incorrect.

Comment: Either through a web server, or via SMS. Depends on what kind of communication.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bump SDK, which is available for both iOS and Android:

http://bu.mp/

Comment: I need to receive messages from n-client iphones at the single android tablet at the office. Is it possible with Bump SDK??